# How to store many ids in another table

Tags: database-design

So I have 2 tables in my database. 1 is called tournament an the other player. 1 player should be able to join as many tournaments as they please. 

Any ideas on how to sotre them?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another table as manytomany relation.
It holds 2 values which both building a unique key. First the player id secondly the tournament id. This way you can make sure a player can join multiple tournaments, tournaments can be joined by multiple players and you dont have redundant data in there. The combination of the 2 keys build the primary and unique key.